# How to remove booleans from a list

Tags: scheme, racket

So for my homework, given a test and an operation, I have to compute the list where the operation is performed only on the elements that pass the tests. An example would be:
(selective-map cons? length (list (list 1 2) empty (list 3)))  => (list 2 1)

I am having a little trouble trying to remove what my fails my test. What I have so far is

```
(define (testfunc test lst2)   
  (cond
    [(null? lst2) null]
    [(false? (map (compose test) (first lst2))) (remove* (list (first lst2)) (lst2))]
    [else (cons (first lst2) (testfunc test (rest lst2)))]))
```

and when I type in the following to test my code `(testfunc cons? (list (list 1 2) '() (list 3)))`, the list does not change. Is there something that I am not looking at correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursion is wrong (you have to test the predicate on each element, why the `map`?), that's not the right way to remove elements and `testfunc` is not the same as `selective-map`, they don't even receive the same number of arguments. Let's try again, from the beginning:

```
(define (selective-map test proc lst)
  (cond
    [(null? lst) null]
    [(not (test (first lst)))
     ; to remove an element we simply don't add it to the output list
     (selective-map test proc (rest lst))]
    [else
     ; on the other hand, an element that passes the test is consed to the output list
     (cons (proc (first lst)) (selective-map test proc (rest lst)))]))
```

A more idiomatic solution would use a folding procedure, instead of explicit recursion:

```
(define (selective-map test proc lst)
  (foldr (lambda (e acc)
           (if (test e)
               (cons (proc e) acc)
               acc))
         null
         lst))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(selective-map cons? length (list (list 1 2) empty (list 3)))
=> '(2 1)
```

Comment: My reasoning was that to map out the boolean for each element in the list and just get the first one from the list and test to see if it was false. If it was false, I wanted to remove that from the list and continue the recursion. If it is true, it will record that point in the new list and continue the recursion. However, I realized that I do not know how to continue the recursion for the second cond statement since my other issue is that if there is more than one empty list, it will only remove one of them and not all of them. Is there a way to deal with this?

Comment: You need to write a procedure that processes a list of lists _recursively_, you can't tell before hand if the list also contains itself another list, and that another list, and so on. I'd start by writing a good set of test cases to make explicit what you expect as output for a series of sample inputs